Storing Data In database of a bubble.io app
I have create a recursive workflow, where I can send the api response data and store the data which is list of items in database with each item having separate entry.
I am using this api https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/token
to get all the applications details.
The response comes like this:
{ "kind": string, "etag": string, "items": [ { object (Activity) } ], "nextPageToken": string }
I have created an api connector api call with use as "Action".
And then created a recursive backend workflow:



